# How to handle numbers bigger than machine representative number?

Tags: java

Assuming now I'm assigning ID number to my database, the database is huge(items more than machine representative number).

I'm using Java, I know the biggest data type in Java is long int(64 bit). How could I deal with numbers bigger than that?

One of my solutions is always converting numbers to strings, which will cause the overhead and I still don't figure out how to accumulate the number(bigger than MAX_VALUE) that is meant to converted to strings.

Comment: Use `BigInteger` for mathematical operations, otherwise keep them as `String`s.

Comment: First figure out whether your data is really a *number*, or whether it's just a text string composed of digits.  There is a difference.

Comment: While this does not impact the answer - a quick back-of-envelope calculation shows that even if your records are 1 byte each, to exceed  long.max_value you would need more storage than humanity is predicted to have for a couple more decades (think exabytes). What's your actual use case?

Comment: Really, you have more than 2^63-1 items in your database? That's a big damn twinkie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/class-use/BigInteger.html).

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("123456789012345678901234567890");
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("314159265");
BigInteger c = a.add(b);
System.out.println(c);
```

Note (1) `BigInteger`s are immutable and (2) you have to use the methods `add`, `subtract`, etc. rather than `+`, `-`, etc.

Also, `BigInteger` (and its floating-point analog, `BigDecimal`) is much lower slower than primitive types. `BigInteger` is fine for most cases, but avoid it if possible in performance sensitive code.

Answer (score 2):

You have specific classes for big numbers in Java, for example [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Answer (score 0):

Java has a class `java.math.BigInteger` in its standard library that is meant to hold (and perform arithmetic on) arbitrarily large integers.

But if you don't need to perform arithmetic, like in the case of a database ID, an ordinary `String` will work just as well.

As to how you can get the number before converting it to a `String`, this depends on how you access the database. If you use the most standard option, *JDBC*, you will at a certain points have a `java.sql.ResultSet`. You can just call the `ResultSet.getString(int columnIndex)` or `ResultSet.getString(String columnName)` methods, even when the column in the database is a number, to get the String from it immediately without going through an intermediate `int` or `long` variable.